# Git pulls without normal merge conflicts

Tags: git, merge

I'm fairly new to Git, and have been working with it for only 3 months.  We previously migrated our repositories from SVN.

I'd like to be able to merge changes from the master into my dev branch without getting "normal merge" conflicts that require "git mergetool", just so I can inspect a change that could have been merged without special notification.

It may just be my previous SVN background, and an expectation that does not carry to Git, but I remember in SVN that I could merge a change from one branch to another, and it only required special attention if there was actually a merge conflict.

In Git, I'm finding I have to do "git mergetool" because any changes in the master always seem to result in a normal merge conflict, even though there are no actual merge conflicts.

Currently, I pull changes from the master, and merge into the dev branch as follows:

```
$ git checkout master
$ git pull
$ git checkout dev
$ git merge master
... [do normal merge conflict thing]
$ git -a commit # though usually this is done via the gui, so I'm not sure of the exact command
$ git push
```

Am I doing something wrong, or missing a config for merges that would be relatively straight forward in SVN, or are my expectations not appropriate for Git?

Comment: Try the push and specify the remote and the branch you want to push to. I.E. git push origin master. I think it's the same thing, but it may be trying to push your dev branch too

Comment: I'm really confused - what do you mean that you get "normal merge conflicts" but no "actual merge conflicts"? (Also, why are you merging your master branch into your dev branch? http://gitster.livejournal.com/42247.html )

Comment: Have you done something odd like set unset the `merge` attribute for all your pathnames? (e.g. `* -‍merge` in `.git/info/attributes` or a `.gitattributes` file)

Comment: @Jefromi - "normal merge conflict" is the message that comes up in Git (from memory).  It's not an actual conflict, but Git still wants me to give it an eyeball.  I'm finding that if I pull directly from the origin master into dev (git pull origin master), I get the behaviour I'm after.. a smooth fetch and merge with no requirements for the mergetool to be fired up.  It's late Friday here, and I have to , so I'll check that article on Monday.

Comment: @Chris J - I don't think so.  I don't seem to have either of those files.

Comment: @Jeffromi - I had a bit more time to read that article.  I'm merging bugfixes from the master branch into the long lived dev branch so the dev branch can be as bug free as possible. In light of the article, my practices are at odds with its recommendations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're doing looks like it should work fine.  I'm guessing it's somewhere else in the process causing the problem.  Having a better idea of what you do to get changes into the master branch might help.  Are you doing anything like in the master branch merging from dev but selectively backing out some changes?

Comment: Perhaps line feeds are different or something, leading to conflicts.

Comment: Sometimes changes into the master are a cherry-pick from a completely different branch (unfortunately, I still have a hangover from the original SVN migration).

Answer (score 0):

i think you want to rebase instead of merge.

i always do

```
#on my master
git fetch origin
git rebase origin/master
git checkout mybranch
git rebase master
```

if you have any uncommitted changes you want to preserve, you can stash them and then after pop them.  its been a while since ive used git (man i miss it) but that routine worked well for me

Comment: rebasing is a great tool, but you don't want to do that if your dev branch is shared or previously published. From the Pro Git Book: "Do not rebase commits that you have pushed to a public repository."

Comment: Rebases are definitely out, since the dev branch is also pushed to as origin/dev

Answer (score 0):

You are not doing anything wrong. This is a perfectly normal work flow, perhaps even the most common. If you constantly get merge conflicts you need to take a look and examine WHY they happen all the time.

For example it might be the case that you have mixed versions of unix and windows line endings, e.g. '\n' or '\r\n'. It might also be the case that you do in fact have normal merge conflicts and if that's the case, you would have the same problem on any other version control system.

Cheers